# How to find the longest odd-even increasing subsequence in python?

Tags: python

I have this problem and I'm not sure about the solution:
Given an integer array A, calculate the length of its longest odd-even increasing subsequence (LOEIS), that is the length of the longest sequence S of elements in A such that all elements of S are odd or even.
For instance, given:  A=[3,9,4,8,6,13,10,26,16,18], because the longest even sequence is made of 5 elements:  [4,6,10,16,18] we have LOEIS(A)=5.

How to code such a function?
Thank you!

Comment: What you have tried so far.

Comment: How is that example the correct answer given that theres an 8 between the 4 and 6 and they're all even numbers?

Comment: There are no odd-even increasing sequences in that list!

Comment: @Sayse What's the issue with the 8?

Comment: @KellyBundy - 8 is a larger number than 6 so it would be decreasing (and ignored in the op's expected output)

Comment: @Sayse Then just leave it out. That's what subsequences do.

Comment: @KellyBundy - Thats what subsets do, i'd expect a subsequence to be a sublist

Comment: @Sayse Subsets/sets aren't ordered, that's not what we have here. Anyway, seems like you should read the [definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence).

Comment: @KellyBundy - Thanks for the link, I'm just going to focus on finding a question that hasn't been abandoned by the OP instead

Comment: @Sayse I'm sorry for not having replied promptly. KellyBundy gave my same interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-longest-increasing-subsequence/ that I've adapted to you issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# A naive Python implementation of LIS problem

""" To make use of recursive calls, this function must return
 two things:
 1) Length of LIS ending with element arr[n-1]. We use
 max_ending_here for this purpose
 2) Overall maximum as the LIS may end with an element
 before arr[n-1] max_ref is used this purpose.
 The value of LIS of full array of size n is stored 
  in * max_ref which is our final result """

# global variable to store the maximum
global maximum


def _lis(arr, n):
    # to allow the access of global variable
    global maximum

    # Base Case
    if n == 1:
        return 1

    # maxEndingHere is the length of LIS ending with arr[n-1]
    maxEndingHere = 1

    """Recursively get all LIS ending with arr[0], arr[1]..arr[n-2]
       IF arr[n-1] is smaller than arr[n-1], and max ending with
       arr[n-1] needs to be updated, then update it"""
    for i in range(1, n):
        res = _lis(arr, i)
        if arr[i - 1] < arr[n - 1] and res + 1 > maxEndingHere:
            maxEndingHere = res + 1

    # Compare maxEndingHere with overall maximum. And
    # update the overall maximum if needed
    maximum = max(maximum, maxEndingHere)

    return maxEndingHere


def lis(arr):
    # to allow the access of global variable
    global maximum

    # length of arr
    n = len(arr)

    # maximum variable holds the result
    maximum = 1

    # The function _lis() stores its result in maximum
    _lis(arr, n)

    return maximum





A=np.array([3,9,4,8,6,13,10,26,16,18])
Even = A[A%2==0]
Odd = A[A%2==1]
print(Even,Odd)

print("Length of lis for Even is", lis(Even))
print("Length of lis for Odd is", lis(Odd))
```

> Length of lis for Even is 5

> Length of lis for Odd is 3

Comment: I didn't downvote but is there a reason you did not use the dynamic programming (which is optimal) approach rather than the brute force approach from your geekforgeeks link?